# how to install postman in elementary os using terminal

Tags: software-installation, thirdpartyapps

I can't install `postman` using the command line...

```
wget https://dl.pstmn.io/download/latest/linux64 -O postman.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzf postman.tar.gz -C /opt
rm postman.tar.gz
sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/Postman /usr/bin/postman
```

Answer (score 6):

```
wget https://dl.pstmn.io/download/latest/linux64 -O postman.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzf postman.tar.gz -C /opt
rm postman.tar.gz
sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/Postman /usr/bin/postman
```

You can also get Postman to show up in the Unity Launcher:

`cat > ~/.local/share/applications/postman.desktop <<EOL`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Postman
Exec=postman
Icon=/opt/Postman/app/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
EOL
```

you  can  download form snapcraft
just  type ur  terminal

```
sudo snap install postman
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, would you accept it so it will be easier to find.